# Extjs TreeStore, more than one asynchronous requests, treepanel rendering dislocation

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6.5, treestore

My extjs version is 6.5,I created a treepanel and GridPanel. When I click the record in GridPanel, the treeStore of treepanel will be triggered to load data. If I click the first record, TreeStore will load more data and slow down, but I have already clicked the second record. At the same time, the second click request has responded. As a result, treepanel will render the response data of the first click.

Ext.data.store does not have this problem. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you produce a fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com) that demonstrates the problem? We really need to see the code and event handlers to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the load event on the treestore 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#event-load

and toggle grid.disableSelection(true); based on selection state
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#cfg-disableSelection

Comment: yes, I listen to the grid beforeselect event, when the isLoading method of treestore return true, return false to stop the grid's select event

Answer (score 0):

Do not do more than one load request at once. [mask](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-mask) the grid on click and [unmask](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-unmask) it, when the store is loaded.